# Interop.zkemkeeper how to connect c#

Tags: c#, dll, device, proximity

I have a bio metric devices to connect C# project.

```
AxInterop.zkemkeeper.dll
Interop.zkemkeeper.dll
Interop.ZKFPEngXControl.dll
zkemkeeper.dll
```

I added to my project and trying to connect the device.

When I create the object "CZKEMClass" this class its getting error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

My code:

```
public zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1;
private bool bIsConnected = false;
private int iMachineNumber = 1;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
}
```

Comment: Is this library 64-bit? Try to open settings of your project and set build target `Any CPU` or `x86`.

Comment: Thank you.. I solve above matter... Thank you very much for your kindly relpy.

Answer (score 3):

I fix the same error by changing the Project build to Plataform Target: x86

1. Open project settings
2. Go on Build > General
3. Then set Plataform target to x86